# Prove that $T^* = -T$

Tags: linear-algebra

So, I encountered a problem in my course book:

"Let $V$ be the vector space of all indefinitely derivable functions of $\mathbb{R}$ that are periodic with period 1, and where $V$ have the inner product $\int_0^1f(t)g(t)dt$.

Prove that $T^* = - T$ where $T^*$ is the adjoint operator to the differential operator T."

My approach was a partial integration where if $T = \frac{d}{dt}$ we get

$$<T f, g> = \int_0^1f'(t)g(t)dt$$
$$=\Big|f(t)g(t)\Big|_0^1-\int_0^1f(t)g'(t)dt$$
$$=\Big|f(t)g(t)\Big|_0^1-<f, T g>$$
$$=(f(1)g(1)-f(0)g(0)-<f, T g>$$

And then if we limit this to the polynomial space, which is $f(0)=f(1)$, we get that $T^* = -T$.

My question now is if this is a solid proof, either if it is incomplete or if I have used a totally wrong approach. I am also interested to know if $T$ is self-adjointed or not. I feel like it is skew-self-adjointed, but I am not sure and I do not know how to prove it.

Comment: You forgot to define $T$ in your statement ...

Comment: Thanks @WhatsUp I have done it now!

Comment: What is the point of your last sentence? The thing about limiting to polynomial space? Your idea is correct and the proof is correct except that it's not done. You're just missing the fact that $f(0) = f(1)$ and $g(0) = g(1)$ imply that $f(1)g(1) - f(0)g(0) = 0$.

Comment: @DionelJaime I kind of just wondered if I had done it right, thanks for the input, I'll add what you wrote to the proof. I thought it was correct to write the limit space for the polynomial, which goes from 0 to 1. Is it unnecessary for the proof? And for the last bit I just wondered about the adjoint. If T is self-adjoint or normal.

Comment: You still have not defined $T$.

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos T is the differential operator, is that not enough for a definition? Because it is all it says in the question.

Comment: That should be part of the statement of the problem. Instead of just writing “the differential operator $T$”, you could have written “the differential operator $T=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}$”. Otherwise, how can we knoe which differential operator you have in mind?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos But the problem in my book is the exact words I wrote, I just assumed that $T=\frac{d}{dt}$. I think you don't get that information, and you have to assume it, as I did.

Comment: @PhythonDaniel I also assumed (as I believe one should) that $T=\frac{d}{dt}$ but just keep in mind there are many other differential operators like, for example, $T=\frac{d^2}{dt^2}+\frac{d}{dt}$

Comment: Also, what you've shown is that $S=-T$ satisfies $$\Big<Tf,g\Big>=\Big<f,Sg\Big>$$ for all $f,g$. You haven't yet shown (but it's not that hard to do) that $S\equiv T^*$

Comment: @MatthewPilling Yeah you are right, I just assumed the "easiest" way to do it, but I definitely keep it in mind, can be good if you want to write an answer with more theory. I'll also show what you wrote in your last sentence as an addition to the problem, thanks a lot for your tip.